# Swift program floats above sign in screen after sleep

Tags: swift, macos

My program needs to stay on top of all programs so I use this code and have it updating every second.

```
view.window?.level = Int(CGShieldingWindowLevel()) + 1
```

Now whenever I put my mac to sleep the program goes over the sign in page. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Let me know if the linked duplicate helped, otherwise I will reopen your question.

Comment: Jal It didn't work. I have issues with it. That is the code I had originally but when the computer sleeps and opens up to the sign in page it goes over the sign in page

Comment: Sure thing, will reopen your question.

Comment: It is strange. Do you know of any way that I could minimize the app when the computer goes to sleep and then open it again when it is awake?